# Bash script for running winzip extarctor?

Tags: bash

I have a script that was  used to extract the zip folder and place it in my destination  folder.

```
 Ex: C:\>"C:\ProgramFiles\Winzip\WINZIP64.exe" -min -e -0 " "C:\TEMP\<filename.zip" "C:\Folder1".
```

currently using,winzip 20.x version and it is failing to run the command.  I have tried several different ways,but it is popping up for the unzip location and i am selecting the location,then it fails to extract.
is there any winzip extension that i have to use to extract these zip files latest?but i can't utilize the extension.please tell me, what is the correct command that i can use to extract and place this destination folder from bash script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What has this got to do with `bash`? Why do you have `<` in the middle of your command? Why have you got double quotes all over the place? Where's the rest of the script? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Ex: C:\>"C:\ProgramFiles\Winzip\WINZIP64.exe" -min -e -0 " "C:\TEMP\<filename.zip>" "C:\Folder1". Here i missed that ending ">" in previous script,so about the rest of the script it will connect to some local repository area and get the zip file from there to windows computer. then extract by using the above command ,so the above script i am using in bash command line.